# remove the child of an element (chess)

Tags: javascript, html, css, chess

I am making a chess game, and I need your help to solve the following problem.

```js
event.target.removeChild(event.target.firstChild);
dragged.parentNode.removeChild(dragged);
event.target.appendChild(dragged);

//dragged is ref to the dragged piece
//event is the drop event
```

when I move a piece :

1. I remove the existing piece from the square
2. I add the new Piece
3. If the square is empty I just add the piece

note: event.target is a square and the pieces are images.

The problem is when I remove The existing piece from the square, I get the following error:
Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that the `event.target` is not what you think it is and that therefore does not have the child element you expect (likely if your pieces are images with transparency that fill a significant part of the parent aquare). The target of an event can be any descendent of the element on which the event listener was set, depending where the event occured.

In other words, if you establish an event listener on the square divs representing squares on the chess board, a click (or drop, or whatever event you listen for) inside the square might easily target the piece and not the square.

Here's an illustration using a click event (but it applies to drops or anything else), a console message reports the target element's id:

```js
const square=document.getElementById("div1");

square.addEventListener('click', event => {
  console.log(event.target.id);
}); // end click listener
```

```css
#div1 {
  width: 50px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  background: yellow;
  padding: 5px;
}

#div2 {
  width: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <div id="div2"></div>
</div>
```

(You can easily check what's going on in your example by putting some console messages inside the event listener to report information about the target)

Personally, I approach tasks like this by making the listener as non-specific as possible (by targetting the document in its entirety). This forces you to test where the event was received and so allows you to cover all bases.

In this working snippet, I've used a click event listener but it will be the same for any event. The listener contains an `if-else` loop that tests whether the outer square or the inner circle was clicked and forms the code required to remove the circle dependent on what the target was:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', event => {

  if (event.target.className == 'square' && event.target.children[0]) {
    event.target.removeChild(event.target.children[0]);
  } else if (event.target.className == 'piece') {
      event.target.parentElement.removeChild(event.target.parentElement.children[0]);
      
  } // end if/else;

}); // end click event listener
```

```css
.square {
   width: 50px;
   aspect-ratio: 1;
   background: yellow;
   padding: 5px;   
}

.piece {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="square">
  <div class="piece"></div>
</div>
```

Note the opening `if` block contains two conditions:

```
(event.target.className == 'square' && event.target.children[0])
```

obviously the first confirms a square was clicked, the second checks whether there's anything inside that element to remove (preventing an error when an empty square is clicked).

Comment: I did the following but i got an error saying that event.target.parentElement is null.              if (event.target.className == "square") {
      event.target.append(dragged);
    } else if (event.target.className == "piece") {
      event.target.parentElement.removeChild(event.target);
      event.target.parentElement.appendChild(dragged);
    } . I don't what is wrong. HELP ME PLEASE

Comment: Is that in a `drop` event listener? (it looks like it should work if so. When you set up your listeners and `if` blocks, leave out the add and remove code and instead use `console.log()` statements to report information about the target, such as its parent element or first child etc. That should guide you. Drag and drop obviously involves several listeners and you have to think about which elements are relevant to each. This jsfiddle might be useful to help you work it out: https://jsfiddle.net/radonirinamaminiaina/zfnj5rv4/